# Nginx чтобы все 404 проходили на php

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

Есть проблема, когда переходишь на картинку, которой не существует, то выводится стандартная 404 ошибка, а хотелось бы, чтобы если нет файла,то дальше шло на index.php. В Apache делал работает, а nginx не получается настроить. Может кто-то подсказать?

```
location / {
    index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
}

location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
    deny  all;
}

#avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

# prevent nginx from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: Покажи, пожалуйста, конфиг location-а, которым обрабатывается запрос этой картинки.

Comment: Добавил конфиг к описанию задания, ещё есть location для php, если надо добавлю и его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Я просто оставлю это здесь.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-nginx-customizing-404-403-error-page/)
В конфиге [`nginx.conf`] добавить так: `error_page 404 = /404.php;`
А `404.php` обрабатывается пыхом.

Comment: огромное спасибо за ссылку, почитал теперь понял по поводу ошибок, и за ответ огромное спасибо =)
добавил так:
    error_page 404 = /;
Просто все идет через index.php

Comment: @TF03, рад был помочь :)

Answer (score 0):

Если это действительно весь конфиг, то достаточно было привести его в порядок:

```
location / {
    index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
}
location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
    deny  all;
}
location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
    deny  all;
}
```